# Convert raster into matrix with R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm currently convert original matrix into a raster to use the focal function, then I would like to convert back the raster into matrix. But I have an error message when I try to use the raster function as.matrix().
Even with this very simple example:

```
r <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
as.matrix(r)
```

Here is what I got:

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :
>
> length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

I'm using RSTUDIO, R version 3.4.0 and `ncdf4`, `raster` and `rgdal` librairies.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that you're using the `as.matrix` function from the `raster` package, not the base version.

I assume you loaded the package with `library` or `require`:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
```

When I use `as.matrix`, it works:

```
> str(as.matrix(r))
 int [1:180, 1:360] 1 361 721 1081 1441 1801 2161 2521 2881 3241 ...
```

When you use the base version of `as.matrix`, you'll get exactly this error message:

```
> base::as.matrix(r)
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

So if only loading the library doesn't work for you, try calling the function like this: `raster::as.matrix(r)`